# Занести id покупателя в MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot, telegram

Задача сделать телеграм бота на Python с базой данных MYSQL. 
Бот при общении с пользователем отправляет кнопку(инлайновая клавиатура), а эта кнопка является ссылкой. 
При нажатии на кнопку(т.е. ссылку) человека перекидывает на сайт free-kassa, где он выбирает удобный ему способ оплаты и оплачивает товар (в моём случае товар является подпиской). 
После чего возвращается обратно в телеграм.
Но я не понимаю, как мне занести в базу данных MYSQL его id (пользователя телеграм, который ОПЛАТИЛ товар), название продукта (который этот id купил) и время покупки. 
Как узнать, что пользователь действительно купил товар (подписку) на free-kassa и занести именно ЕГО id в бд?
Подскажите пожалуйста, что для этого нужно, как это вообще реализовать?
Как решить эту задачу, именно чтобы добавлялись эти данные: (id, название продукта, время покупки) в базу данных MYSQL.

Comment: Необходимо занести в бд не просто id пользователя, который написал боту, а именно покупателя, и время покупки товара. Не понимаю как проверить и как вообще узнать id покупателя, если оплачивает он на сайте free-kassa. Подскажите пожалуйста, может я просто не правильно понял, как занести в бд время покупки товара, id покупателя и название продукта

Comment: Записывайте в базу всех пользователей. При нажатии на кнопку можно отследить кто нажал.

Comment: Пользователь ведь мог нажать на кнопку, его перенесло бы на free-kassa, но он бы допустим не стал оплачивать, а просто вернулся в телеграм канал.

Comment: Есть api для free-kassa, читайте. Скорее всего как то так, вы создаете новую cdkre на платеж. И вставляете в кнопку. И проверяете если оплачено то разрешаете доступ.

Comment: https://www.free-kassa.ru/docs/api.php

Comment: Могли бы утчнить что такое cdkre?

Comment: Это я слово ссылка неправильно написал.

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, на free-kassa есть документация по API, мне поможет ответ в формате JSON? не буду использовать бд, нужно просто получить данные, а именно id пользователя и название продукта. Но с чего мне их получать, я не въезжаю. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Читайте https://www.free-kassa.ru/docs/api.php здесь все написано